# Glimpse execution tab disabled for MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I have just installed Glimpse for MVC3 from nuget and I have logginEnabled set to true in web config but still do not get the "Execution" tab. This is on IIS Express.

I have another project which does not use IIS Express (uses visual studio dev web server) and I can see the execution tab.

I have checked my web.config  and I have all the sections configured.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clear your log file, kill IIS Express, and then start it up again and make 1 request and post the resultant log file?

Comment: sorry, but can you tell me which log file?

Comment: I have an IISExpress log file, where can I post it? (never posted on SO before)

Comment: You can post the example file to [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) if you'd like.

Comment: Also, you may want to [update to the latest version 1.1 of Glimpse for MVC3](https://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc3/).